# How can I pass entire react state with post request

Tags: ajax, reactjs, axios

I was thinking about passing entire react state with post request using axios

So, this is what I did

```
 axios.post("/profile", (
          {state: this.state}
        )).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log("this is error", error)
        })
        this.props.history.replace('/home');
      }
```

but Probably this is not how you send entire state with post request. So let's say this is my post request

```
state = {
  bestAchievement: "",
  secondaySports: "",
  dob: "",
  primarySports: "",
  role: "",
  role1: "",
  phone: "",
  userid: "",
  address: "",
  state: "",
  city: "",
  pinCode: "",
  bio: ""
}
```

Which I want send to my node route at once, How can I do it?

Ps: This is my node route

```
router.post("/", authCheck, (req, res) =>  {
    console.log("this is post data")
    console.log(req.body) //This is logging undefined

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `axios.post` is a key-value object with data you want to send to the server, so just `this.state` will work fine.

```
axios.post("/profile", this.state).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("this is error", error);
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer with how my node route looks, I tried this before but console.log in my node route logs undefined. 

Also, I am sure data is being added in my state (or my state have data)

Comment: @KuchBhi Your router says `"/"`. Are you setting it to `"/profile"` somewhere else? Do you have a [body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) that parses the request body?

Comment: I was missing body Parser. Anyway, I added `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); ` and then whenever I make a post request to the `/profile` route,  it logs just `{}`  for `console.log(req.body)` Can you please also tell how could I View this data in console.log or what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: @KuchBhi You are not sending URL encoded data, but JSON data. Try `app.use(bodyParser.json());` instead.